# Finding rows where col A & B match and sum of col C = 0

Tags: excel

[image]

Hi all,

I am looking for a way to find rows under the following conditions:

Values of column A matches, values of column B matches AND values of column C add to 0.

I've tried sumproduct on conditional formatting without much success.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$1:$C$9)*($A$1:$A$9=$A1)*($B$1:$B$9=$B1))=0
```

Perhaps `VLOOKUP` could be used? Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to find where Column A = Column B ; Col C = 0? Why not use an `IF` formula with a nested `AND`? If I'm not mistaken on your question I'd use something like this:
`=if(and([ColA]=[ColB],[ColC]=0), [ do stuff ], [ do other stuff]`, otherwise you may have to rephrase your question as it's unclear what the conditions are. Unsure why a vlookup or sumproduct needs to be invoked.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. "Values of column A matches values of column C" for what rows? All of them? Some of them? Until some condition is reached? Are you comparing 9 rows as shown in your example above? Groups of 9 rows? We need some help understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DavidRichardson  Since his second highlighted set is row 7 and 8 but not 9, I think he means until the sum=0 condition is met.  Row 7 and 8 or row 7 and 9 would each do that but all the rows with 1015 and B wouldn't.

Comment: Your sumproduct is wrong  It should probably be `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$9=$A8),--($B$2:$B$9=$B8),$C$2:$C$9)` but even then it doesn't do what you want because it doesn't produce 0 for your second set with 1015 and B.  It sums all the rows that have 1015 and B (rows 7, 8 and 9) and produces the sum of 50.  But you don't want it to sum all the rows with 1015 and B - you only want to sum them up until they are 0 (so just row 7 and 8).

Comment: Does the running total of a given A-B value pair ever cross from positive to negative (or negative to positive) without a row where the running total is zero? I e. For a given A and B value, might their C values ever be [-100, 50, 60, 50], causing the running total for that A-B pair to be [ -100, -50, **10**, 60], crossing from negative to positive without a **0** in between?

Comment: @jerry jeremiah Got it, thanks. Looking at this again, I see only two ways to do this. VB code to find a subset of rows and highlight, or use helper columns to identity the subset of rows. May need helper sets as well - not sure. Also need assume that colA+colB combos are mutually exclusive of other sets, or else you can't get an accurate answer. I'll play with it if I have time later today.

Comment: @DavidRichardson  I tried with helper columns and almost got it.  But I think a VBA macro would be way easier...

Comment: I recommend using a pivot table. `Deal` in columns, `Item` in rows, sum of `USD` in table.

Comment: @jerry jeremiah I added an answer below with helper columns. I think this does with the OP needed, but it may not if I don't fully understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a huge table and you want all rows where A and B match, try this:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9, $A$2:$A$9, A2, $B$2:$B$9, B2) = 0
```

Or, if you highlight your rectangle and **Insert - Table** then make a new column with a formula of

```
=SUMIFS([USD], [Deal], [@Deal], [Item], [@Item]) = 0
```

then use that column for your conditional formatting formulas and, if you wish, hide the column. That way it's easier to read, you only need to enter the formula once instead of dragging it down the column, and it will store it once instead of once per row.

If it is a huge table then you are going to want to make a pivot table and then use that, because executing this for every row in your raw table will probably be a lot slower than a pivot table would, but using a pivot table is less user-friendly because the changes aren't instant unless you do some VBA to refresh the pivot table anytime something changes.

Comment: Your formula doesn't find his second highlighted set for 1015.  Actually, I don't think he is trying to highlight the rows if ALL of them have matching A and B and the sum of ALL of them is 0 - I think he is trying to highlight the subset of rows that sum to 0 that have matching A and B.  Finding a subset will be tricky because it will require permutations because that second set could be row 7 and 8 or row 7 and 9.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. Yes, I hadn't noticed the significance of the highlighting, but I feared that's what he was actually, which is why I had included the "all rows where A and B match" caveat.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm using two helper columns. You could hide these in your spreadsheet. Col E = colA & colB. Col F has this formula:

```
SUMIFS(C$1:C$8, E$1:E$8, E1) = 0
```

This says if the sum of values in col C = 0 where col E matches the current row, TRUE, otherwise FALSE.

Then I added a conditional rule for A1:C8 to highlight in yellow. The rule is

```
=$F1
```

This says to highlight the row if the col F is true for that row. I *think* this will do what you want.

Note that my highlighted results are different than yours. You show 2 rows of 1015 in Col A + B in Col B as highlighted. Why would this be? (50) + 50 + 50 does not = 0? (Thanks to Jerry J for pointing this out.)

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes any difference but your A8 cell doesn't contain the same value as the A8 cell in the question...

Comment: @Jerry Ugh... unfortunate typo because it does matter. It brings up a question for the OP:  he shows the first 2 rows of 1015 + B highlighted. I don't see what logic would do this. There are 3 rows of 1015 + B and Col C doesn't total to 0 for them.

Comment: I think he wants to highlight rows (grouped by column A and B) until the running sum in C reaches 0 - but that implies using VBA to loop through highlighting rows until the sum is 0 or finding all permutations of rows with the same A and B and choosing one that has a sum of 0.  I thought maybe there was a way to do that with helper columns - and I got close but not quite there.

Comment: @Jerry Ahh.... until the running sum is 0, but not necessarily all matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone more clever than I can figure out how to do it without helper columns.  Until then, here is one way to do it:

You need just one helper column - a column that does a running total for each value of A and B.  So, put this in D2 and copy it down all the way to D9:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C2,$A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,$B2)
```

That will sum all the values above the current cell that have the same A and B.  What that does is find where the rows finally sum to zero.

Then you can use this in your conditional formatting:

```
=COUNTIFS($D2:$D$9,0,$A2:$A$9,$A2,$B2:$B$9,$B2)
```

That will find the zero below the current cell that has the same A and B.  So, it doesn't include cells that have the same A and B that are below the 0.

If you put that second formula in E2 and copy it down all the way to E9 it looks like this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Deal | Item | USD | Running Total | Conditional Formatting |
| 1010 | A | 100 | 100 | 1 |
| 1015 | A | -100 | -100 | 0 |
| 1010 | A | -99 | 1 | 1 |
| 1010 | A | -1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1010 | B | -100 | -100 | 0 |
| 1015 | B | -50 | -50 | 1 |
| 1015 | B | 50 | 0 | 1 |
| 1015 | B | 50 | 50 | 0 |